Tomcat Web Application Not Loading Correctly in Docker Container: HTTP Status 404
I am running a TomEE server inside a Docker container, but my web application is not loading as expected. Here is the setup I'm using:
Docker Image and Container:
Image: interesting_picture:latest (created 4 minutes ago)
Container Name: beautiful_swartz
Port Mapping: 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
Tomcat Directory Structure: Inside the container, I navigated to the /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/ directory, which contains the following files:
index.jsp  META-INF  prompt.jsp  result.jsp  WEB-INF
Docker Folder Structure: ->Dockerfile and ->ROOT.war of my application
Problem: When I access http://localhost:8080 in my browser, it just shows an HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
Apache Tomcat/11.0.0-M24
What I Have Tried:
1)Checked that the container is running and the port is correctly mapped.
2)Verified that the files are in the /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/ directory.
3)Restarted the Docker container.
Additional Information:
Docker version: Docker version 27.1.1, build 6312585
TomEE version: TomeEE 10.1.25
Host OS: macOS Ventura 13.3.1 (22E261)
Why is my Tomcat web application not loading correctly, and how can I ensure that my custom JSP files are served by Tomcat in the Docker container?

Have you checked logs?
docker logs beautiful_swartz

Please [edit] the question to include a [mcve].  Details like your Dockerfile and the actual docker run command will be more interesting than after-the-fact diatnostic output.
